# Design pattern for child class that contains child property

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm wondering if there is a design pattern that would solve this problem.
I have a structure that looks like this:

```
    public abstract class DBAccess
    {
         protected MetaData MetaData;
    }

    public class OldDBAccess: DBAccess
    {
         //this class will set metatData = new OldDBMetaData(); in the constructor
    }

    public class NewDBAccess: DBAccess
    {
         //this class will set metaData = new NewMetaData(); in the constructor
    }

    public abstract class MetaData
    {
        //some variables and methods that belong to all MetaData objects
    }

    public class OldMetaData : MetaData
    {
        string oldName;
        //some variables and methods that belong to only OldDBMetaData objects
    }

    public class NewMetaData : MetaData
    {
        //some variables and methods that belong to only NewDBMetaData
    }
```

I want to be able to call a method in OldDBAcess that sets properties that belong to OldDBMetaData.  Since metaData is a MetaData object and not an OldDBMetaData object, I've had to do this so far:

```
    //method in OldDBAccess
    public void SetOldName(string name)
    {
       if(metaData is OldMetaData)
       {
           OldMetaData metaData = (OldMetaData)MetaData;
            if (metaData == null)
                // metaData isn't of type OldMetaData
            else
                metaData.oldName = name;
        }
     }
```

This works just fine, I just don't want to have to check that metaData is of type OldMetaData every time I call a method.  I know that it's of this type because I set it to this type in the constructor.  I want to use the metaData property in either of the derived classes or the base class, so I can't just create properties in each of the DBAccess classes.  Is there a design pattern or some easy way to do this with this kind of structure?

Comment: I think there are important missing pieces to your question. For example, you say that OldDBMetaData is new'd in the constructor of OldDBAccess. And then you provide a method called SetOldName which you say is a method of OldDBAccess. Therefore, OldDBAccess already knows exactly the type since it constructed it. Also, in your sample method class names are changed  (is AccountMetaData the same as MetaData? Is OldDBMetaData the same as OldMetaData?) and it's confusing the question.

Comment: Do you want calls to obsolete properties and methods (things that are in `OldMetaData` but not `NewMetaData`) to just be no-ops?

Comment: @TrevorAsh, you're right, I did have some method class names that were inconsistent.  I fixed them now so they should make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

This may do what you need:

```
public sealed class OldDbAccess : DbAccess
{
    protected override MetaData CreateMetaData()
    {
        // return old metadata
    }
}

public class DbAccess
{
    public DbAccess()
    {
        this.MetaData = CreateMetaData();
    }

    protected virtual MetaData CreateMetaData()
    {
        // return new metadata
    }
}
```

If you're using ReSharper (or similar) it may bark at you about calling virtual members in the constructor, but that should be fine as long as your `CreateMetaData()` call doesn't rely on anything that's set up in the derived class's constructor.

Comment: This works, but it's not the problem I'm having.  My code already does something like this.  The problem I have is that in OldDBAccess when I try to set any properties that only belong to the OldDBMetaData class, I have to check to make sure that MetaData is of type OldDBMetaData before I have access to them.  I want a way to do this without checking the type every time because I know that if I'm in a method in OldDBAccess the type of MetaData is OldDBMetaData

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from your case, it is some thing like this:

```
public abstract class MetaData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class OldDBMetaData : MetaData
{
    public string OldName { get; set; }
}

public class NewDBMetaData : MetaData
{
    public string NewName { get; set; }
}
```

For instance, your problems will be occurred in the TestSetName method

```
public abstract class DBAccess
{
    protected MetaData metaData;
}

public class OldDBAccess : DBAccess
{
    public OldDBAccess()
    {
        metaData = new OldDBMetaData();
    }

    public void TestSetName(string name)
    {
        // You want to do this one, but you cannot because the abstract class MetaData doest not exist OldName property
        // metaData.OldName = name;

        // I can simple resolve this problem by cast this to the OldDBMetaData
           ((OldDBMetaData)metaData.OldName) = name; 
    }
}
```

In my point of view, we can resolve this by CAST, but it will be coupled on the implementation. If you want to avoid that, you can create another abstractions for OldDBMetaData and NewDBMetaData.